# listing all the pages of a custom content type

Tags: theming, nodes

I would like to know the appropriate way to listing the contents in a single page of type "news". Let me clear it once again, I have a "news" type custom content type.

Now i want to list all the pages of type "news" in a separate(say about us) page and styling them. Prior to this I have created a template file in my custom theme's template directory named as "node-news.tpl.php". Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use views module to generate a page to display all node of news content type.

- Install a views module
- Go to administrator -> structure -> views
- Add new view
- Add filter content type as "news"
- Add fields to views.

Comment: Yes that is quite easy, but i need to list all the pages without using view module and also database query .Can it be possible using some code in template.php or anywhere else??

Comment: You need to create a custom module and can write the custom query in the module.

Answer (score 1):

The [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module do that. There's many articles about this question. Take a look on existing answers

Answer (score 0):

generate a View using the view module as mentioned by Satyabrata sahoo. generate a page view for your specific purpose that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it in your template file .
Drupal suggest names for the custom content type template files.

```
 and it is page--node--your_content_type.tpl.php .
```

You can see your nodes of type (your_content_type) at here.